# Java Android Data Binding : what is the difference between @Bindable and @BindingAdapter

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-mvvm

i just learn about MVVM pattern in java android using [two way] data binding, and i'm confuse about the usage of both annotation.
in 1 article, the example is setting the observable data using @Bindable and notifyPropertyChanged, and in another article, the writer is using @BindingAdapter in his example.
what is the difference between both ? it seems both annotation are having the same purpose and when i should use @Bindable over @BindingAdapter ?

Below is some code reference : 
For Bindable (taken from : https://androidwave.com/working-with-observable-data-object-using-data-binding/)

```
@Bindable
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
}
```

For BindingAdapter (taken from : https://androidwave.com/android-data-binding-recyclerview/)

```
@BindingAdapter({ "avatar" })
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageURL) {
  Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
      .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
          .circleCrop())
      .load(imageURL)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
      .into(imageView);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

BindingAdapter is to create custom binding method if the attribute that you want to bind is not implemented by android framework. On the other hand, Bindable is for binding the data to the view. For clarity, you can imagine Binding adapter as custom key but bindable as value for a key.